# Schedule AutoHotKey Script

Tags: date, autohotkey, schedule

I have an AutoHotKey script that is functioning properly to log me in to my WordPress dashboard.

I want to add a schedule to run this script:

- Run this script at 9am every day
- Excluding Saturday and Sunday
- Excluding specific dates (Example: Christmas day this year 12/25/17)

Here is the current code

```
; Start script, open website login URL
Run http://www.digitango.com/wp-login.php

; Wait for page to fully load
Sleep, 2000

; Click Username Field
Click, 850, 430

; Selected all items in input field
Send, ^{a}

; Remove all from input field
Send, {Del}

; Enter User Name
Send, username

; Click Password Field
Click, 850, 510

; Selected all items in input field
Send, ^{a}

; Remove all from input field
Send, {Del}

; Enter Password
Send, password

; Click Login Button
Click, 1075, 560

; Wait f
Sleep, 2000

; Notify script has started
MsgBox, You successully logged in automatically!

; Enable exit script by hitting escape key
Esc::ExitApp

; End Script
Return
```

Comment: off the top of my head... trigger your script through TaskScheduler, in your script, pull today's date and run some evaluation on it to find out if today's day is between monday and friday, and not Dec 25. If today's day is a good day, then go on with your login script, otherwise get out and see you tomorrow @ 9am.[Calculate dates](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/72923-calculate-dates/)

Comment: just thinking out loud here... you could achieve the same thing using TaskScheduler/Bat/Firefox/TamperMonkey or a similar cocktail. Task Scheduler would trigger your Bat file, your bat file would launch Firefox at your desired url, then your TamperMonkey script would take care of login you in if today's day qualifies.

Comment: You can also set only weekdays in TaskScheduler, but not specific exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

This does not address your question of doing it all in AutoHotKey, I'm sorry. What I am providing, is the basic JavaScript to do it in [TamperMonkey FF](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tampermonkey/) or [TamperMonkey Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en).

If you were to go with this solution, you would simply have to make Bat file that gets triggered by a Scheduled Task. Your bat file would launch your preferred browser, at your desired URL, and from there, TamperMonkey would take care of evaluating today's date to decide if you should get logged in or not. Please note this uses Javascript, and months are represented from 0 to 11(not 1 to 12 as you would normally expect), hence why `new Date(2017, 11, 25)` is actually `December 25 2017` and not `November 25 2017`.

```
//
//TamperMonkey script
//
var workDays = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday"];//set your working days
var holidays = [new Date(2017, 11, 25).setHours(0, 0, 0, 0), new Date("2017", "11", "6").setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)];//set your holidays
var today = new Date();//get today's date

/*
This function will return the name of the day
*/
function getDayName(dateStr, locale) {
    var date = new Date(dateStr);
    return date.toLocaleDateString(locale, { weekday: 'long' });
}

/*
If today's day is in the workDays array, and today is not in the hollidays array
Then login
Else Don't log in
*/
if (workDays.indexOf(getDayName(today, "en-US")) > -1 && holidays.indexOf(new Date(today).setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)) == -1) {
    console.log("working today");
    document.getElementById("user_login").value = "your username";//enter your username
    document.getElementById("user_pass").value = "your pwd";//enter your password
    document.getElementById("wp-submit").click();//click the login button
}
else {
    console.log("not working today");
}
```

**Following up**. The only missing portion here is TaskScheduler. So what I have is a bat file that launches FireFox @ www.google.com. Once the page loads, TamperMonkey takes over and evaluates today's date. If today's date is a good day, it automatically inserts text in the text field, and the button gets clicked.

I created a bat file "GetMeThere.bat"
In that file, I wrote:

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" "www.google.com"

In TamperMonkey, I created a new script and this is everything that's in it.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         SearchOnGoogleOnWorkDays
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @match        https://www.google.ca*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

//
//TamperMonkey script
//
var workDays = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday"];//set your working days
var holidays = [new Date(2017, 11, 25).setHours(0, 0, 0, 0), new Date("2017", "11", "6").setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)];//set your holidays
var today = new Date();//get today's date

/*
This function will return the name of the day
*/
function getDayName(dateStr, locale) {
    var date = new Date(dateStr);
    return date.toLocaleDateString(locale, { weekday: 'long' });
}

/*
If today's day is in the workDays array, and today is not in the hollidays array
Then login
Else Don't log in
*/
if (workDays.indexOf(getDayName(today, "en-US")) > -1 && holidays.indexOf(new Date(today).setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)) == -1) {
    console.log("working today");
    //document.getElementById("user_login").value = "your username";//enter your username
    //document.getElementById("user_pass").value = "your pwd";//enter your password
    //document.getElementById("wp-submit").click();//click the login button
    document.getElementById("lst-ib").value = "search for this";
    var els = document.getElementsByName("btnK");
    console.log(els);
    if(els != null){els[0].click();}
}
else {
    console.log("not working today");
}
```

**Please note** I put this together very quickly to prove the concept. My posted TamperMonkey script, as-is, goes into an infinite search loop because this `// @match        https://www.google.ca*` is much too broad for production code. But it proves the concept does work. If I double click my bat file, Firefox launches at www.google.com then TamperMonkey automatically does my search.

Comment: I am going to have to try this, I think it might be a better solution.

Comment: Can you elaborate or point me in a direction for how to setup the Bat file?

Comment: @HeckRaiser, Yes, I'll write it locally, test it and then I'll update my answer.

Comment: @HeckRaiser, updated my answer with a "**Following Up**"